# Как удалить, получить объект в Django REST по pk и по другому полю?

Tags: django, http, url, django-rest-framework

urls.py:

```
url(r'^myapi/(?P<pk>\d+)/', MyAPI.as_view()), 
url(r'^myapi$', MyAPI.as_view()),
```

views.py:

```
class MyModelAPI(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = MyModel

    ...
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method in ['PUT', 'POST']:
            return MyModelIdSerializerBasic
        return MyModelSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('order')

  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...


  def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        try:
            myitem = self.model.objects.get(myitem_id=pk, user=request.user)
            myitem.delete()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

serializers.py:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    myitem = MySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

class MyModelIdSerializerBasic(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

Для удаления по pk вызываю DELETE /myapp/номер/ для получения всего списка вызываю GET /myapp для получения объекта по pk - GET /myapp/номер/

Если добавляю для третьего варианта

```
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
            if request.method == 'GET':
                try:
                    myitem = self.model.objects.get(myitem_id=pk, user=request.user)
                    return Response(myitem, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Перестает работать второй (получение всего списка), т.к. на GET срабатывает эта функция get(...), а при GET /myapp нет параметра pk.

Как решить эту проблему?

И как добавить получение и удаление объекта не по pk, а по любому другому полю?